# Responsive DataGrid Bootstrap

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that is embedded in a responsive bootstrap table.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:DataGrid ID="MonthlyBillGrid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                    EnableViewState="false" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                    </asp:Table>
                </div>
```

My question is, how can I make this datagrid view look like this: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_striped&stacked=h

I already have loaded the data into it... it just doesn't look good on my site, because my whole site is in bootstrap...

Can someone please give me some advice as to how to make my `DataGrid` look like the above link?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried loading in the style sheets from the example in the link?

Comment: Yes, I have. I just think it isn't liking when you try and style a gridview

Comment: Did you also set the `class` of the table to `table table-striped`

Comment: Yeah I have done that as well